# Vapor 4 - Approaching an issue - Return type of a function

Tags: ios, swift, fluent, vapor

I have a function that triggers when I hit a certain endpoint, that contains some sort of a condition inside

```
if room exists {
    return room
} else {
    create a new room and return it
}
```

The issue is, that sometimes I return an EventLoopFuture (if the room doesn't exist), and sometimes I return a Room type without an EventLoopFuture (if a room exists), so I am not quite sure what the return type of the function should be.

Now the way I fix it is with a hacky workaround, where I always return an EventLoopFuture, and if the room exists, I update it and return it, which is totally unnecessary as there's nothing to update.

Would the right way be to save the newly created room and return it separately, so the condition will always return a Room type and not an EventLoopFuture?

The original function:

```
func findEmpty(req:Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Room> {
    guard let category = req.parameters.get("category") else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
    
    try checkIfAllowed(category: category)
    
    return Room.query(on: req.db)
        .filter(\.$category == category)
        .all()
        .flatMap { relevantRooms in
            for room in relevantRooms {
                for isOccupied in room.availablePositions {
                    if !isOccupied {
                        return room.update(on: req.db)
                            .map {
                                return room
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            let newRoom = Room(...//initializing room)
            return newRoom.save(on: req.db)
                .map {
                    return newRoom
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of `async`, you can choose to return either the `Future` or the resolved value. However, in most cases, the `async` pattern results in simpler code. If you do want to return a `Future` of your `room`, then it should be as simple as replacing your existing `return room` with `return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(room)` instead of the unnecessary `update`. so:

```swift
return room.update(on: req.db).map {
    return room
}
```

Becomes:

```swift
return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(room)
```

Converting code using `Future` pattern to `async` is relatively straightforward (and if it isn't that's probably a sign you should leave it as `Future`). In your case:

```swift
func findEmpty(req:Request) async throws -> Room {
    guard let category = req.parameters.get("category") else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
    
    try checkIfAllowed(category: category)
    
    let relevantRooms = try await Room.query(on: req.db)
        .filter(\.$category == category)
        .all()
    for room in relevantRooms {
        for isOccupied in room.availablePositions {
            if !isOccupied {
                return room
            }
        }
    }
    let newRoom = Room(...//initializing room)
    try await newRoom.save(on: req.db)
    return newRoom
}
```

Just an observation, but your inner `for` could be replaced with something simpler:

```swift
if let unoccupied = room.availablePositions.first { !$0.isOccupied } {
    return unoccupied
}
```